# Solving weak 2 body problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I tried to solve a physics problem about two body problem where the masses $M$ and $m$ are $M \gg m$.
The body $m$ is at radius $R$ from the mass $M$ and is falling down with initial speed $v(0) = 0$.
I need to calculate the time of falling.

The point is not how can I solve it the problem (I have found a better way).

I tried to find the solution it by solving the differential equation 
$$\ddot x(t) = \frac{k}{x(t)^2}$$
but had no success.
The way I tried is the following:
$$
\dot x \ddot x = \frac{k}{x^2} \dot x \\
\frac{1}{2} D[(\dot x)^2] = k \frac{\dot x}{x^2} \\
\int \frac{1}{2} D[(\dot x)^2]\ dt = k \int \frac{\dot x}{x^2}dt\\
\frac{1}{2}(\dot x)^2 = -k \frac{1}{x} + C \\
\dot x = \sqrt{-2k\frac{1}{x} + C}
$$

which doesn't seem correct to me.

I want to solve it using clever tecniques (by clever I mean multiply or add a nice terms and make calculations almost instant).

Could you suggest me something?

Comment: There's a lot wrong with what you did. You can't multiply through by $x'$ if it might be zero; and all your integration steps are just not valid calculus. Probably the best way to begin working with this problem analytically is to assume a power series expansion, which from the initial conditions would be $x(t) = R + \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k t^k$. Then $x^2 = R^2 + 2 R \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k t^k + \left ( \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k t^k \right )^2$. Let $K=k/R^2$ and use the geometric series, then attempt to equate coefficients of the series on each side of the equation.

Comment: @Ian: Actually, this looks pretty much entirely right to me. First, note that since the mass starts at rest and then starts falling, the velocity $\dot{x}$ will never be zero after $t=0$. Consequently the multiplication is valid. Next, by recognizing that the entire expression is a total derivative, one integrates and obtains the first integral of the motion.

Comment: I see only one problem, and it's a physics issue: you need $\ddot{x}<0$ in order for this to start falling (i.e. for $x$ to get smaller). If you account for that, then it's entirely correct as far as I can tell. (You also have a typo: the $\ddot{x}$ on your RHS should be $\dot{x}$).

Comment: The left side manipulations are fine. The right side manipulations don't even make sense. The left side was integrated with respect to $t$ but as written the right side was integrated with respect to $x$. What was desired, and is correct, is $\int x'/x^2 dt = -1/x + C$. That was not written, and I didn't even realize until just now that that was intended. Otherwise you've made good points.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking the calculations! The most problematic thing here is manipulating higher order derivatives and for this reason I couldn't understand that $dx$ is wrong, $dt$ is correct. Sorry doing mess writing the solution, now I fix it.

Comment: Another point is I can try to solve the final differential equation by direct integration. But it seems ugly and I'm looking for a nicer way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done seems correct to me - and also quite simple. You got the multiply-by-$\dot{x}$ trick which is the 'standard' way to solve this. I think it will be hard finding a much easier route. To complete the solution, you only need to fix the value of $C$ and integrate up once more. This is also fairly simple since from

$$\dot{x} = \sqrt{-\frac{2k}{x}+C}$$

we can use $v(0)=0 \to C = \frac{2k}{R}$ (particle starts at $x=R$ and falls to $x=0$) and then (using $k=-GM$)

$$T =\int dt = \int \frac{dx}{\dot{x}} = \int_{0}^{R} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{R}-\frac{2k}{x}}} = \sqrt{\frac{R^3}{2GM}}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1}} = \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac{R^3}{2GM}}$$

Solving the last integral is probably the most tricky part here (I cheated using math software). Also, from a 'physics point of view', all the important parts have already been done when you get to that last integral. What remains is just a calculation (which in principle can be done numerically if you cannot solve it).

EDIT: Another way to get to the $\dot{x}$ equation above is to use conservation of energy during the fall. The total energy is equal to the initial energy:

$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 - \frac{GMm}{x} = \frac{1}{2}m0^2 - \frac{GMm}{R}$$

which gives

$$\dot{x} = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{x} - \frac{2GM}{R}}$$

directly.

Comment: Doing $y=\sin^2\phi$ gets the job done. But you're quite right---once you've got the overall constant out from, all that's left is a number which you might as well as a computer for (sayeth the physicist.)

Comment: Thank you. It's a good solution. With Semiclassical's substitution it works well.